# How to pass column name into parameter in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I am trying to create a xml from a dataframe .  Issue that I am facing i want pass column into paramter and its not working.

```
    ORDER_NO        1175        1304          1421  
   7283630          2019-12-04  2019-12-10   2019-12-12 
   7283650          2019-12-25  NaN          2019-12-20
```

**My code**

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>"""

for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        f.write(body.format(col[2], row[2], col[3],row[3],col[4],row[4]))
```

I want to pass then columnname wherever STS={} is coming.

**Expected output**

```
<ORD> 7283630</ORD>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1175">
<DTM>2019-12-04</DTM>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1304">
<DTM>2019-12-10</DTM>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1421">
<DTM>22019-12-12</DTM>
```

How can this be done in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python count from `0` in indexing subtract `1` from selecting columns names like `cols[2]` to `cols[1]` for all values:

```
cols = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        f.write(body.format(cols[1], row[2], cols[2],row[3],cols[3],row[4]))
```

---

```
<ORD>7283630</ORD>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1175">
<DTM>2019-12-04</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1304">
<DTM>2019-12-10</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1421">
<DTM>2019-12-12</DTM>
</osi:ORDSTSINF>
```

EDIT:

More dynamic solution with `loop`:

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>"""

cols = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        for c, r in zip(row[2:], cols[1:]):
            f.write(body.format(r, c))
```

EDIT1: For mit missing values add [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html):

```
header = """<ORD>{}</ORD>"""
body ="""
<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="{}">
<DTM>{}</DTM>"""

cols = df.columns
for row in df.itertuples():
    with open(f'{row[1]}.xml', 'w') as f:
        f.write(header.format(row[1]))
        for c, r in zip(row[2:], cols[1:]):
            if pd.notna(c):
                f.write(body.format(r, c))
```

Comment: @jezrael, Thanks it works . Is there another easy  way of writing body statement. Here I based on number of columns ,I am duplicating statement . Instead  canwe automatically create number body lines needed based on columns and pass the value

Comment: I have more question,for record 2 number in data frame value of column 1304 is NaN. Then I want remove body being generated for 1304 column and keep the rest. In general wherever NaN is occurring that part has excluded from the body.Can that be done?

Comment: @aeapen so in output is 5 times `<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE=`? Now I am offline, on phone only, so tomorrow should be added solution.

Comment: I dont want `<osi:ORDSTSINF types:STSCDE="1304">
<DTM>NaN</DTM>` to be created  but for 1175 &1421 the XML  itshould be generated. In Short , I want the code skip the XML generation when  row values for STS_CDE is `NaN`.

Comment: for record 1 in the data frame ,xml should generated for all status codes but for record 2 only 1175 and 1421 should be created avoiding `NaN`